# Java 8 Collector.groupingBy classifier value in downstream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

What will be a proper way to provide classifier value into supplier function of the collector in the following example:

```
import static java.math.BigDecimal.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collector.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static class Item {
        String key;
        BigDecimal a;
        BigDecimal b;
        public Item(String key, BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
            this.key = key;
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }
        public BigDecimal getA() {
            return a;
        }
        public BigDecimal getB() {
            return b;
        }


    }
    public static class ItemSum {
        public ItemSum() {
        }

        public ItemSum(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
        String key;
        BigDecimal sumA = ZERO;
        BigDecimal sumB = ZERO;
        public void add(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
            sumA = sumA.add(a);
            sumB = sumB.add(b);
        }

        public ItemSum merge(ItemSum is) {
            sumA = sumA.add(is.getSumA());
            sumB = sumB.add(is.getSumB());
            return this;
        }
        public BigDecimal getSumA() {
            return sumA;
        }
        public BigDecimal getSumB() {
            return sumB;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, ItemSum> map = list().stream().collect(
                groupingBy(Item::getKey, 
                        of(
                                ItemSum::new, 
                                (s,i) -> {s.add(i.getA(), i.getB());},
                                (i,j) -> {return i.merge(j);}
                                )
                        )
                );
        map.forEach((k,v) -> {System.out.println(String.format("%s: A: %s: B: %s", k, v.getSumA(), v.getSumB()));});
    }

    public static List<Item> list() {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>(3);
        list.add(new Item("a", ONE, ONE));
        list.add(new Item("a", ONE, ONE));
        list.add(new Item("b", ONE, ONE));
        return list;
    }

}
```

The problem is to pass *key* value into *ItemSum* during construction time. I've got some workarounds to populate key field afterwards but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in supplier and eliminate default constructor of *ItemSum*.

Comment: Could you explain in English what you want to do? Or provide a sample input / output? It would make it easier to understand.

Comment: I want to provide "key" value into the supplier of ItemSum. Now  ItemSum::new method reference is used. But I also need to populate "key" field of every ItemSum. For example, consider that there is no default constructor for ItemSum only the one with the "key" argument.

Comment: @Tunaki I believe he wants `ItemSum` to be initialized with the key that comes from the classification function that is used in `Collectors.groupingBy()`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes, that is

Comment: @alsid you have the key in every `Item` element that is passed to the downstream collector

Comment: @alsid `Supplier` only creates a new instance without passing arguments. So you have to initialize it in your `ItemSum::add` method.

Comment: @Flown this is one of the ways. But in this case ItemSum have a default constructor which I want to avoid.

Comment: @alsid As I said `Supplier` looks like: `() -> new ItemSum()`. Therefore you can't use the current `key`. Anyway the `key` is stored as the key of the map so there is no need for duplicating in the `ItemSum`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a job for the [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) collector, not the `groupingBy` collector.

Let's add a constructor

```
public ItemSum(Item item) {
    this.key = item.getKey();
    this.sumA = item.getA();
    this.sumB = item.getB();
}
```

to the class `ItemSum`. This constructor initializes one `ItemSum` based on an `Item`. You can then remove the default constructor (it won't be needed). Then you can simply have the following:

```
Map<String, ItemSum> map = 
    list().stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getKey, ItemSum::new, ItemSum::merge));
```

What this does is that is collects each `Item` element into a map classified by the key of each `Item`. For the value, we initialize it with a single `ItemSum`. When multiple values are encountered for the same key, we merge them together.

Comment: Thanks. Looks elegant!

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't do it the way you want.

If you make your `ItemSum` class receive an `Item` instance in your `add`  method (the accumulator method of the collector), you could easily achieve what you want:

```
public class ItemSum {

    String key;

    BigDecimal sumA = ZERO;

    BigDecimal sumB = ZERO;

    public void add(Item item) {
        key = item.getKey();
        sumA = sumA.add(item.getA());
        sumB = sumB.add(item.getB());
    }

    public ItemSum merge(ItemSum is) {
        sumA = sumA.add(is.getSumA());
        sumB = sumB.add(is.getSumB());
        return this;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSumA() {
        return sumA;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSumB() {
        return sumB;
    }
}
```

Then, use it this way:

```
Map<String, ItemSum> map = list().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Item::getKey, 
        Collector.of(
            ItemSum::new, 
            ItemSum::add,
            ItemSum::merge)));
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. It's basically how it works for me now - initializing key in add operation.  Example code I provided was meant to show a problem. I really like @Tunaki suggestion.

Comment: I also like his answer more than my own :) His approach is the best one for your case